# Saving user registration data from DRF to Postgresql database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i am building an app with an user registration with the help of django rest framework, i want to store my user's data in my postgresql database, i can see my model on my pgAdmin but after made a post request to register my user i cant retrieve my data on the database.

So how can i save those data on the database ?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.


class User(models.Model):
    
    username = models.TextField()
    email = models.TextField()
    password = models.TextField()
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ( 'username', 'email', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer

class UserCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

Main project urls.py file :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include , path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('templateApp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

App urls.py file :

```
from .views import UserCreateAPIView
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/register/', UserCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='register'),
]
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistake in what you have written. Could you share the urls.py and the client code making the POST request? Besides, why do you use such a custom model ? Unless you have very good reasons to do it, you should probably use the default Django mecanisms (if this is because you want to add your own fields, you can extend the default User class by inheriting the AbstractUser class : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: Hi thanks for ur answer , i've edited my question so u can see the urls.py files, for the POST request i did it in postman. @MickaelMartinez

Comment: Erf.. im so sorry, i wasnt watching on the right DB , my bad there is no problem now ...

Answer (score 0):

I used the api/login/ and passed the username and password in this format-
{
"username": "trevor",
"password": "Password@123"
}

And got a response on the LoginAPI.view() as -

{
"expiry":
**"token"**:cef5dd74b1e8fba6b5f496e7de8d0674505f45ac6f62a0d6aa9ac061bccb8b7d
}

Then on terminal I used the command-

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/logout/ -H 'Authorization: Token cef5dd74b1e8fba6b5f496e7de8d0674505f45ac6f62a0d6aa9ac061bccb8b7d'
```

The token got deleted after this.

You can verify all this at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin under knox tokens.

I hope this helps